# Chinese national phone line can not use Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-play-services

China BNM phone is not Google play server, can not use Google Map, but why can WeChat? WeChat using Google Map Web version of it?

Answer (score 0):

The acces to google maps in China is based on a different link. http://maps.google.cn.

For accessing the  the Google Maps APIs in China you should access by  the domain maps.google.cn.

This domain does not support https. Then  when your  link for requests to the Google Maps APIs from China,  replace https://maps.googleapis.com with http://maps.google.cn.